Getting : "An error occurred while calling o110.pyWriteDynamicFrame. Exception thrown in awaitResult:" in AWS Glue Job
I am getting "An error occurred while calling o110.pyWriteDynamicFrame. Exception is thrown in awaitResult:" in AWS Glue Job.
The size of my source data in s3 is around 60 GB.
I am reading data from s3 adding a transformation for filtering out the garbage data using regex then, mapping out the columns to the ones in my Redshift table, and storing it in Redshift.
The job ran for 2 hrs then it threw this error.
Here's what my Glue script looks like.
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue import DynamicFrame
import re

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

AWSGlueDataCatalog_node = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database="database_name", table_name="table_name", transformation_ctx="AWSGlueDataCatalog_node")

regex_pattern = r'^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\+0000$'

Filter_node = Filter.apply(frame = AWSGlueDataCatalog_node, f = lambda x: bool(re.match(regex_pattern, x["col0"])), transformation_ctx="Filter_node")


ChangeSchema_node = ApplyMapping.apply(frame=Filter_node, mappings=[("col0", "string", "active_at", "string"), ("col1", "string", "client_id", "string"), ("col2", "string", "profile_uuid", "string")], transformation_ctx="ChangeSchema_node")


AmazonRedshift_node = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame=ChangeSchema_node, connection_type="redshift", connection_options={"redshiftTmpDir": "s3://aws-glue-assets/temporary", "useConnectionProperties": "true", "dbtable": "dbtable", "connectionName": "connectionName", "preactions": "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name (active_at VARCHAR, client_id VARCHAR, profile_uuid VARCHAR);"}, transformation_ctx="AmazonRedshift_node")

job.commit()


Most DynamicFrame-related Glue error messages I’ve seen will usually begin with what you have in the title. But, somewhere in the middle of the message (literally the middle), is a line starting with “Caused by” or something similar. That may give a better explanation as to why the error occurred.
